# phonegap keep running javascript when changing pages

Tags: javascript, html, cordova

i'm deploying an application using phonegap. When im at page A.html, im doing a login to a notification server. in page A.html, i have a javascript called pushClient.js (when there is a new data, the server will push a notification to this client). I check my login status at here (page A.html) is true.

inside A.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/pushClient.js"></script>
function checkLogin() {
 alert(login.isLogin);
}
function loginToNotification() {
loginTomyNotServer(callback) 
// this is inside pushClient.js
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", "mynotServer.com/login?id=myid", true)
req.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'Keep-Alive');
req.onreadystatechange = handlemymessage
req.send()
//
}
function callback() {
  // do something
}
function goToNextPage() {
window.location = "B.html";
}

<body>
<button onclick = "checkLogin();"> check login </button>
<button onclick = "loginToNotification();"> login to server </button>
<button onclick = "goToNextPage();"> goto next page </button>
</body>
```

but the problem is, when i change to page B.html, and go back to page A.html i got disconnected from the notification. i check my login status at page A.html (without login again) it returns false.

it seems that when i change to page B.html, the page A.html is "destroyed"

is there a way to keep my pushClient.js keep running when i change page ??

Comment: Can you explain more about how you change pages? If you are maintaining state across pages I think you will need to pull in new content rather than loading a completely new page (ie single-page application approach).

Comment: im using javascript to change the page, like this :         window.location = "B.html";                                                could be this the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i found that i will need a background services something like this https://github.com/Red-Folder/Cordova-Plugin-BackgroundService